# Limit Theorems for the ArgMax of Function?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a continuous, infinitely differentiable function $f_n(x)$. I know the functional form of the function and any of its derivatives. I know $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I'm interested in $x_n^* = \text{argmax} ~ f_n(x)$. Is there any way I can show $x_n^* \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Any theorems that might put bounds on $x_n^*$?

I know in general this isn't true, but based on the problem at hand and some simulations I'm almost certain it has to be the case for my function $f_n$.

If it's helpful $f_n(x) = g_n''(x) / ( 1+[g_n'(x)]^2 )^{3/2}$ and $g_n(x) = b_{1,n} x^{-1} + \dots + b_{p,n} x^{-p}$ for some given $p \in \mathbb{N}$. ($f_n(x)$ is the signed curvature of $g_n(x)$.) The functions are defined on $[0,\infty)$ and $x \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}_+$. It's the $b_{j,n}$'s that go to zero.

I thought of directly solving for $x_n^* = \text{argmax} ~ f_n(x)$ by finding $x_n^*$ as the solution to $f'_n(x) = 0$, but solving $f'_n(x)=0$ for $x$ doesn't seem feasible. Any help would be really appreciated!!!

Comment: Where are these functions defined, $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry forgot to add that. They're defined on $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a>0$.

Comment: If that's true, how could $x_n^*\to 0$?

Comment: Good point! $g_n(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$, but $f_n(x)$ needs to be defined on $[0,\infty)$ I guess. ($f_n(x)$ is the curvature of $g_n(x)$ and I know the curvature has to go to zero.)

Comment: ??? The $f_n$'s are defined where the $g_n$'s are defined.

Comment: Sorry! It's been a long day... I was thinking about the $x$'s. The functions are defined on $[0,\infty)$. The $x$'s take values in $x \in [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.